# How to add properties to prototypes (javascript)

Tags: javascript, oop

The following function `Phone()` creates a prototype and `Phone.prototype.screenSize = 6;` adds the `screenSize` property

```
function Phone() {
  this.operatingSystem = 'Android';
}

Phone.prototype.screenSize = 6;
```

then if we made a new object `myPhone` and checked if it contains the `screenSize` property it returns false although the property was added before creating the object.

```
const myPhone = new Phone();

const inherited = myPhone.hasOwnProperty('screenSize');

console.log(inherited);
// false
```

**Why doesn't it return true and how to make it return true**

Comment: "*Why doesn't it return true*" `hasOwnProperty` checks the *object* and explicitly *not* the prototype chain.

Comment: how to check the prototype chain?

Comment: It's not a property of the new object, it's a property of its prototype.

Comment: "*how to make it return true*" what is your goal? Do you want to make sure `hasOwnProperty` returns true? Then you need to attach the property to the instance. Do you want to verify the property *exists*? Then use [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in). This seems a bit like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: + didn't the `screenSize` became part of the chain just like `operatingSystem`? @VLAZ

Comment: @MinusFour that's what I wanted to know

Comment: `operatingSystem` is explicitly attached to each instance at construction time.

Comment: my goal was to know why does it return true for `operatingSystem` and false for `screenSize` but thanks for you and @MinusFour now I know the difference @VLAZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why doesn't `hasOwnProperty` return true?

Because it's not an **own** property of `myPhone`, it's inherited from the prototype object.

> how to check the prototype chain?

Use the `in` operator instead.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a property type to prototype will only add the "own" property to prototype and not the instance.

```
Phone.prototype.screenSize = 6;
Phone.prototype.hasOwnProperty('screenSize'); // true


const myPhone = new Phone();
myPhone.hasOwnProperty('screenSize'); // false
// instances will not own the property.
```